# (TypeScript) When I assign a value to object it does not contain methods, but when I initilize an object it contains methods, can anyone explain this

Tags: typescript, oop, object

In typescript, when I initialize an object with data it does not contains methods. But when I initialize it as a object it contains methods. Why is that?
See bellow example.

```
let a = {a: 12, b: false}

class Data {
    private a: Number;
    private b: Boolean;

    print() {
        console.log('Default print')
    }
}

let x: Data  = a;
x.print

let y: Data = new Data()
y.print()
```

variable `y` contains print() method. but `x` does not.

Comment: That’s because `print()` is a public method on your class and not a static method.

Comment: Depending on your settings, this [doesn't even compile](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAhhC8EG8oC4IEYBMAaCAjVAZlMAM4gC+AUJQMbBQkkQAiUYMClE3EADgE4BLAG5sQ0VADkArgFtcIfgG4uPASLF5UAIQD2u0FAB2K1d3VGwACgCUiMz241dRkgZAA6YLoDmVgOTMIETSwJAWYP42DlRUlKCQAB6orOzc8FAqzq7uXr5WiR4RttHx4BAAnilsMPBGIADuLDW2lBVFQpatQA), the compiler correctly complains that print is missing when you try to assign a to x. What's your question?

Comment: my question is, is x and y are same or not? if not then why. I tried to access print() method through variable x but I could not. But it was possible with the variable y.

Answer (score 1):

`print()` is a method of your class, not a static method of the scope that `x` is in.

By assigning `y` to `new Data()`, you are initializing it as an instance of your `Data` class, so it has access to the `print()` method.

You don't do that with `x`; you're telling the TypeScript compiler that the type of `x` should be `Data`, but then assigning it to an object literal that doesn't match that type. Because of this, the code above throws a type error:
`TS2741 [ERROR]: Property 'print' is missing in type '{ a: number; b: boolean; }' but required in type 'Data'. let x: Data  = a;`

The TypeScript type you give to a variable won't affect the actual value of that variable, it will just throw a type error if the value assigned to it doesn't match the given type.

The last two paragraphs of [the Type Annotations section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#type-annotations) in the TS docs might help clarify. Your code will still be compiled to JavaScript, and run, just maybe not as you are expecting. However, you should still see the type error when compiling with `tsc`.